# "INVALID CROSS REFERENCE ID" IN DATALOADER

Tags: data-loader, upsert, invalid

I am trying to  do upsert through data loader.It is throwing the following error for all rows in the csv file.The ids used in the csv file are correct.I got those ids from url. Please Help!

> ERROR:   "INVALID CROSS REFERENCE ID"

Comment: Your ID values are not correct. Either they are not of the correct type, or you do not have access to that ID. For example, if you're copying data from one org to another, lookup fields will need to be updated with the correct ID values in the destination org. Despite what you think, you've made an error somewhere.

Comment: Fields labels in my csv files are: ID(Case_owner_history),case ID,Tier,Business Days,Case Owner,Start Time,End Time,Transferred to,Escalated.Is there thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's a sample row look like?

Comment: a1bt00000002IjhAAE,,II,0.7,Queue: Tier II,8/25/2017 16:46,8/28/2017 12:46,Queue: Tier III - CNAe-Tools,TRUE

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, at minimum, the Case Owner field is incorrect. Case Owner reads "Queue: Tier II", which is not a Salesforce ID. You will need to locate the Queue's ID (Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Queues), and place this in your CSV file. In addition, the Transferred To field also appears to be a user/queue lookup field, so you may need to adjust this field as well. Also, Case ID is null, but should probably be a non-null value. If you're doing this from a report, I suggest that you actually try running a SOQL query from the Data Loader to make sure you get a good look at how the data is supposed to be.

Comment: I tested the same file except for ID field in Dev sandbox.. It successfully updated the records. There is no need for Queue ID  to be included. Case Owner is not a ID field, its a text field. I am manually creating the file because of the values to be updated in production. So what makes the difference between DEV and PROD org.I checked the field level security. Its same as in DEV.

Comment: @UmaN If not that field, then `a1bt00000002IjhAAE` is not a valid Id in production. Make sure you check the ID value.

Comment: I created brand new csv file using notepad++ and uploaded the data. It worked  fine without any errors.